# iOS Best practice for handling model objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, model, persistence

There are different levels I'm asking this question at.

Case 1: Let's think about the typical drill-down design. Say a table view controller has an array of custom objects, and tapping a cell will push a view controller that allows the user to modify the object represented by the cell. In this case, should the pushed view controller have the custom object as a property of its own, or use a data source/delegate protocol to edit the custom object but not own it.

Case 2: A similar but slightly different situation is this. I'm using a singleton store to handle an array of bank accounts in my app. A view controller will show a list of the accounts, and I'm wondering if I should have the array of accounts as a property in my view controller or get the array via the store. (The array of accounts is accessed quite often.) I guess the only difference is a single object vs. an array of objects. I'm curious about how heavy these arrays can be, so whether it's faster to load the array from the store each time or have it as a property in the view controller.

Case 3: When should the local file system be used? In my app's example, bank accounts are accessed quite often, so I have them unarchived and set as properties upon launching the app, but for much bigger data, I only load them from the file system when they should be displayed or edited. I'm still not sure what the right way is.

Comment: I tested to see how much time it takes to unarchive an object, and it was quite slow so I'm thinking objects that are accessed often should be properties, but how big is okay?

Comment: This question is too broad and also IMHO off-topic for StackOverflow. You may want to ask it on [programmer.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What should be the topic for stack overflow then?

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).